# Can slimes spawn in chunks surrounding slimechunks

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have recently build a new slimefarm using the coordinates I got from the [slimefinder](http://mcslimes.appspot.com/).

The location I am building in has a lot of slime chunks. I have chosen 2 chunks next to each other to build the spawning pads, and used an non-slime chunk in front of them as the collection/lookout are.

I have noticed that slimes are spawning in all 3 chunks, even though slimefinder says it's an empty chunk.

So what is wrong here?

- Can slimes spawn outside the borders of the slimechunk.
- Do I have my calculations wrong (I highly doubt it)?
- Could it have something to do with my world being generated in 1.2.5?

I want to know for sure, because if they do spawn in surrounding chunks, I'm going to half slab down the caves I just lit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Slimes can only spawn in chunks where they are allowed. Why are there slimes in chunks that shouldn't have them?

1. **Slimes move around**. Chances are this is what happens. They will bounce (ooze? slide?) to different chunks over time. This can include falling from higher heights.
2. **You used or read the slime chunk calculator wrong**. Maybe you punched in the seed wrong or chose the wrong map. Maybe you misread your map? Double check you if you needed to have a "-" (negative sign) on your coordinates. Double check your calculator.

This may or may not apply to your spawning pads but slimes can spawn at any light level, unlike other mobs like skeletons, zombies, etc.

For reference: Minecraft Wiki - Slime     https://minecraft.wiki/w/Slime

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late comment. I have checked the calculations multiple times and all is well. Further, the non-slime chunck is completely walled in now, so no slimes can bounce into it. Yet there are slimes there, really strange.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe it is due to how the spawning mechanism works in general. See the wiki:

"*If the pack location is suitable, 12 attempts are made to spawn up to 4 mobs (8 for Wolves, 1 for Ghasts) within a 41x1x41 area centered at that block (that's a 41x41 square that is one block high). Mobs will spawn with the lowest part of their body inside this area. For each spawn attempt, a block location within the pack area is chosen at random. Though the pack area extends 21 blocks out from the center, the random location is heavily skewed toward the center of the pack. Approximately 85% of spawns will be within 5 blocks of the pack center, and 99% within 10 blocks of the center.*"

Assuming it chooses an air block at the edge of your eligible chunk as the spawn center, this might cause it to spawn outside the chunk.

Answer (score 0):

They do not spawn but may wander into them.